# Setting up docker-compose, uwsgi, Django and nginx, for Pycharm, makes nginx return 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: nginx, docker, pycharm, docker-compose, uwsgi

I have a common set up of docker+nginx+uwsgi+django (latest versions) that works fine, **until** I try to use **Pycharm** in order to run/debug inside the running uwsgi container, in which case I get a 502 from nginx.

My `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'

services:
  db:
      image: postgres:9.6
      env_file: src/myapp/settings/local.env
      ports:
        - "2532:5432"

  web:
      container_name: myc
      build: .
      env_file: src/myapp/settings/local.env
      links:
          - db:db

  nginx:
      build: ./config/nginx
      volumes_from:
        - web
      links:
          - web:web
      ports:
          - "5656:80"
```

My `Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.5

EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["/bin/bash", "./bin/run-uwsgi.sh"]

ENV PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/app/src/:/app/src/myapp/
ENV DEV_PROD development
ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE src.myapp.settings.$DEV_PROD

# goes on installing several things...
```

My `./bin/run-uwsgi.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

python ./src/manage.py migrate --noinput
/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --uid deploy --gid deploy --http 0.0.0.0:8000 --master --processes 4 --threads 2 --module src.myapp.wsgi
```

My nginx configuration file:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name _;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

  location /docs {
    alias /app/docs/_build/html;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://web:8000;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

Everything works fine if I do:

```
sudo docker-compose build && sudo docker-compose up -d
```

My Pycharm Setup that screws up everything:

1) Setting up docker server

[image: setting up docker server]

2) Setting up the interpreter:

[image]

3) Creating a RUN/DEBUG configuration:

[image]

If I run through Pycharm when I visit `http://localhost:5656/` I get a `502` response.

```
sudo docker-compose logs nginx
..
nginx_1  | 2017/06/05 15:46:57 [error] 7#7: *35 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.18.0.1, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.18.0.4:8000/", host: "localhost:5656"
nginx_1  | 172.18.0.1 - - [05/Jun/2017:15:46:57 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 174 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: You can try to publish the port of the web component, because it probably does not lift well and so nginx can not access the port ..

Comment: exporting `ports` at `web` container in `docker-compose.yml` results in an instant connection reset error when ran through pycharm. Accessed successfully when pycharm is stopped.

` wget localhost 8008` gives: 
`Connecting to localhost (localhost)|::1|:8008... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.`

Comment: Probably i missing some part... in your post talk about port 8000, but in your comment talk about 8008. That is right?

Comment: In order to try out what you suggested in your comment, I added an additional rule `-ports: 8008:8000` to `web` just to get nginx out of the way.